# I am having a hard time understanding how to pass a prop in React and how to render it to the browser

Tags: reactjs

**my code:**

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      partyType: "birthday",
      entertainment: "clowns",
      venue: {
        name: "Polly's Party Palace",
        capacity: 120,
       }
      cakeFlavor: "vanilla"
      };
     }

  render() {
     return ( 
       <div>
           <h3>Party Time!</h3>  
              <p> This {this.props.partyType} party will be held at 
               {this.props.venue.name} with a maximum capacity of            
               {this.props.venue.capacity}. </p>
               <p> Featured entertainment: {this.props.entertainment}! 
               We will serve a {this.props.cakeFlavor} cake.</p>
      </div>
      );
     }
    render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Party partyType={this.state.partyType} entertainment= 
        {this.state.entertainment} venue={this.state.venue} cakeflavor= 
        {this.state.cakeFlavor} />;
      </div>
    );
  }
}
       
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

I am trying to:

1. pass the partyType, entertainment, and venue properties from the state
2. create/define a new React component named Party, that includes the paragraph elements you see in the code.

**my issue:**
I can not get this code to render to the browser (show up as sentences/party invite) I don't know if I am missing anything, or what I am doing wrong.

If it helps I have included the instructions below:

Challenge 1: Between the div tags at lines 18 and 20 of the JS section, render a component named  and pass the partyType, entertainment, and venue properties from the state.

Challenge 2: Create/define a new React component named Party. In it, have it return a div that contains h3 tags surrounding the words Party Time!, followed by two paragraph elements that use the passed-in props. The first paragraph element will say: This _____ party will be held at ______ with a maximum capacity of ____. The second paragraph element will say: Featured entertainment: ______! The blanks will be filled in using props. See the screenshot in the learning portal page for this code challenge.

Comment: Is not clear at all your question, please consider to format the code correctly

Comment: I reformated the code, I hope this is clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like maybe a bad copy paste? This is how I would do it:

```
function Party({ partyType, entertainment, venue, cakeFlavor }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Party Time!</h3>
      <p>
        This {partyType} party will be held at
        {venue.name} with a maximum capacity of
        {venue.capacity}.{" "}
      </p>
      <p>
        Featured entertainment: {entertainment}! We will serve a {cakeFlavor}{" "}
        cake.
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    partyType: "birthday",
    entertainment: "clowns",
    venue: {
      name: "Polly's Party Palace",
      capacity: 120,
    },
    cakeFlavor: "vanilla",
  });

  const { partyType, entertainment, venue, cakeFlavor } = state;

  return (
    <Party
      partyType={partyType}
      entertainment={entertainment}
      venue={venue}
      cakeflavor={cakeFlavor}
    />
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```